# How to migrate data from 2.0.X to 2.2.X

Tags: data-migration, magento-upgrade

I have a magento 2.0.15 installation which I want to replace with a fresh installation of latest version 2.2.2

I'm not able to upgrade existing version to the latest one. I checked data migration tool, but it only supports migration from 1.9.x to 2.x

Any ideas how to migrate data from one version to another?

Comment: Why would you like to do afresh install? Why not use the built in upgrade tool (web or cli)? The backup tool can be used to create a backup, which you can import in a fresh install. I’ve exprienced some glitches with both tools, so be prepared.

Comment: in built admin web is not able to upgrade, I upgraded my test setup from server side using command line. Upgrade went fine, but when I check my shop, it has lot of problems. Nothing seems to work anymore. That is why I'm looking a way to start from fresh setup and migrate the data.

Comment: It would be good you show what errors you get after doing the CLI-upgrade. It could be easy to fix and be due to server configuration or know bugs. You could get same issues if you do a fresh install...

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below commands in CLI :

**NOTE : Please take backup of you files and database**

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
chmod +x bin/magento
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

**Keep you website in developer mode while upgrade so you fix the bugs.
Also, You will have to update your modules and theme.**

Comment: Since backup is from 2.0.X version, is it compatible to restore on a much later version like 2.2.2, As I said in my previous post my attempt to upgrade seems to be not working.